# How to scroll down each section using fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I am referring to the [documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/) however it doesn't seem to work the way it is intended to. 
**My code:**

```
 $('#moveDown').click(function(){
    $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
 });
```

What i am trying to build is a clickable fixed element at the bottom right to navigate down each section for the user. It only seems to work with `$.fn.fullpage.setAutoScrolling(true);` set to true and with `continuousVertical:true` set to true and it wont move unless i scroll up and then click #moveDown. Any help out there?

**EDIT**

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fullPage.css" />
  <script>
   //initialize fullpage scrolling
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    //Navigation
    menu: false,
    anchors: ['Home', 'Anonymous', 'Real Reviews', 'More', 'The App', 'Who'],
            autoScrolling:false,

    //Accessibility
    keyboardScrolling: true,

    //Design
    resize : false,

    });
    //remove styles and scripts related to fullPage for mobile
    if (screen.width < 479) {
        $.fn.fullpage.destroy('all');
        $("section, .section, div").removeClass("mid-text");
         }
    else{
        $.fn.fullpage.reBuild('all');
         }
    $('#moveDown').click(function(){
        $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();

        });

    });
    </script>
```

This is how i have my full page code laid out. I checked my errors however there are just files i am not using. I removed those files and cleared some of the errors but cant seem to find the problem. The only thing i cant think is a conflict between plugins?

**UPDATE:**
In between each div with the class section i had `<div style="clear:both"></div>` which was the problem. Everything works perfect now.

Comment: Please add a link to the reproduction of your problem. Your description doesn't provide a way to reproduce it as you can see in [this demo I made](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/409/) where the function `moveSectionDown` works as expected.

Comment: Hi Alvaro, Great plugin. but i seem to have some trouble. I am fairly new to javascript so pardon the broken question. Here is a [link](http://mylandlordscore.com/new_index_final.php) to where i am attempting to apply the #moveDown click.

Comment: Your site is full of errors. Review the javascript console using Chrome inspector or FireBug for Firefox. Once you solve them, then you can try to check you problem again. Meanwhile, I am sure the problem is not of fullPage.js.